# Logic works halfway but not completely

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, data-structures

I am trying to remove duplicates from a sorted list.

```
nums = [0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4]

for i in range(len(nums)):
   a = nums.count(i)
   if(a>1):
      nums.pop(i)
```

I am getting `[0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4]` but am expecting `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`.

I see the logic I used worked halfway and removed duplicates until the value 2 but for some reason I don't understand it didn't work for the value 3.

Comment: List and array is not the same in Python. You have a list. I recommend rewording and changing the tags appropriately

Comment: If you can use the `builtins`, consider using `set()` to remove duplicates.

Comment: I know that you are trying to do this on your own, which I'm sure you are very close to achieving. If you are really just trying to remove duplicates and keep it in a list, though, you can just do `list(set(nums))`.

Comment: @ketanRudrurkar - did at least one of the answers help you? Please consider accepting the best one if so.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic won't exactly work here. Since you're looping through the number of items in the list and the length of the list is changing, you are at risk at running into an error (`IndexError`).

Here's another way to approach this problem.

```
nums = [0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4]
new_list = []

for i in range(len(nums)):
   num = nums[i]
   if num not in new_list:
       new_list.append(num)

print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
nums = [0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4]

seen_n = set()
for i, n in reversed(list(enumerate(nums))):
    if n in seen_n:
        del nums[i]
    else:
        seen_n.add(n)
print(nums)
```

Prints:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

If you are iterating the elements by index number, then you need to remove the elements in reverse order so that the indices of the next elements you visit are not affected by the deletions of previous element. In this code we simply keep track of every unique value we see in a set and test each element of the list against membership in that set to see if it should be deleted.

I just wanted to add that there are many ways to solve this problem. But the question posed was, "Remove duplicates from a list." I take this literally and do not consider creating a second list with duplicates removed to be the same thing as removing duplicates from the original list. You have to ask yourself what if there are other references to the original list? Will they see the change? No.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in your misunderstanding of `nums.pop(i)` : it won't delete all the `i` items, it would delete just that single item having index `i`.

So that `nums.pop(3)` deletes the second `2` item.

```
# [0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4]
# [  0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4]
# [  0,  1,1,2,2,3,3,4]
# [  0,  1,  2,2,3,3,4]
# [  0,  1,  2,  3,3,4]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a different approach, but it may be worth mentioning that you can also remove duplicates by converting to a dict and back.

```py
nums = [0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4]
nums = list(dict.fromkeys(nums))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are already lots of answers to this question, but it seems to me none of them are doing the obvious optimization that comes from the fact that the list is sorted, which means that if a number is a duplicate, it is necessarily identical to its predecessor.

This is how I would solve the question, then, using `prev_n != n` as the most efficient way to know `n` has not been seen yet:

```py
nums = [0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4]

uniq_nums = [nums[0]]
prev_n = nums[0]
for n in nums:
    if prev_n != n:
       uniq_nums.append(n)
       prev_n = n

print(uniq_nums)
```

Answer (score -2):

try using two lists

```
nums = [0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4]
nums2 = []
for i in nums:
    if i not in nums2: nums2.append(i)
print(nums2)
```

*edit: previous solution was ineffective, whoops*

Comment: it is not working for nums = [2,2,2,3,4,4] too. It gives a pop index out of range error.

Comment: Your test case is not much of a test case but the code looks like it should work. Your `if else` statement can be simplified to `if i not in nums2: nums2.append(i)` or `if not i in nums2: nums2.append(i)`.